# var ByteArray VS byte[] array: garbage collector behavior

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Last week, i made a code interview.

My interviewer said:
"What do you prefer between

```
  var byteArray = myFunction();
  and
  byte[] Array = myFunction();" ?
```

I answered, once compiled, theses lines give the same result.

And my interviewer said: "Yes, but they are not garbaged the same way: var byteArray is better because GC garbages the variable quickly."

I'm very astonished that two lines of code giving the same result once compiled are not garbaged the same way, but maybe i'm wrong.

So: Are they garbaged the same way or not ? If not, can you explain me why ?

Comment: Obligatory [TryRoslyn](https://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:>ilr/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcBYAUAB2ACMAbMAYxnJIEMQQYBhGAbzxg5kNIpgCEEaANoBdGAFkEAMWARyyMAHsIACgCU7Tm1yddMAE6pkwfRBgRUAdxhFBqIQEYADE5E4dnAL6aOPrsTJKADdFMAATCXVWP10gmn0bOwYAXglpWXklVTV3PU4YzjAAMxgVWzQQIVcYAEJUpw0PPO08vOQAC31FawtrAFEAD3JUfAVldVzW7yaYad0/bkCYEPCYADkoltby+zEdlLSZOTHsydbWgo5i0v2qsTqYBsvomfOOrp6rGEHh0ayJ55zLx4TxAA==) showing that both codes generate the same

Comment: (generate the same IL assembly code... the sentence got truncated :-( )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they are garbage collected the same way. Same types, same behavior. This is a *compiler feature*: once compiled, there is nothing what makes the one code different than the other.

Comment: @Christophe: you can only [accept one answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (the one with the green check mark). You can upvote all others. Accept the answer that helped you most.

Comment: No problem. SO can be a hard place to understand, but once you do, it's fun.

Comment: For what it's worth I too like this answer the best too: it concentrates on the facts. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 4):

They are exactly the same, assuming there's no implicit conversion to `byte[]` involved. There's no way for them to be different, since `var` is just syntactic sugar that gets replaced with the proper type.

Answer (score 4):

Your interviewer was incorrect.

In your particular case, `var` stands in for `byte[]`. The code is equivalent.

Perhaps your interviewer was thinking, in error, that the first case in a sense creates one object, but the second case creates several. Hogwash, of course.